# How do you set the tab size in a JEditorPane?

Tags: java, swing, jeditorpane

A `JTextArea`'s tab size can easily be set using `setTabSize(int)`.

Is there a similar way to do it with a `JEditorPane`?

Right now, text with tabs in my pane looks like:

```
if (stuff){
            more stuff;
}
```

And, I'd prefer a much smaller tab stop:

```
if (stuff){
    more stuff;
}
```

Comment: http://java-sl.com/tip_default_tabstop_size.html you can check this

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As JEditorPane is designed to support different kinds of content types, it does not provide a way to specify a "tab size" directly, because the meaning of that should be defined by the content model.
However when you use a model that's a PlainDocument or one of its descendants, there is a "tabSizeAttribute"  that provides what you are looking for.

Example:

```
JEditorPane pane = new JEditorPane(...);
...
Document doc = pane.getDocument();
if (doc instanceof PlainDocument) {
    doc.putProperty(PlainDocument.tabSizeAttribute, 8);
}
...
```

From the Javadoc:

```
/**
 * Name of the attribute that specifies the tab
 * size for tabs contained in the content.  The
 * type for the value is Integer.
 */
public static final String tabSizeAttribute = "tabSize";
```

Comment: Thanks for not just a 'how', but a 'why' too!

Comment: For Styled EditorKit it's also possible http://java-sl.com/tip_default_tabstop_size.html

Answer (score 6):

In case anyone's using a StyledDocument (The link on the other answer died)

You create a TabSet which is an array of TabStops. In my case I only cared about the 1st tab, and I wanted it 20px from the left, so this code worked for me:

```java
StyleContext sc = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext();
TabSet tabs = new TabSet(new TabStop[] { new TabStop(20) });
AttributeSet paraSet = sc.addAttribute(SimpleAttributeSet.EMPTY, StyleConstants.TabSet, tabs);
pane.setParagraphAttributes(paraSet, false);
```

Answer (score -1):

Took me a while to figure this out.
And decided to use TabStop's in a TabSet that have calculated width based on the font size.
This has to be reset when ever the font size changes (in the paint() method of the JEditPane).

Complicated stuff! :(

Comment: This isn't an answer!